# Is it allowed to sign your program with your own certificate?

Tags: signing

I don't want to buy an overpriced code certificate.

Am I allowed to ask the user if he wants to install my certificate and then I install my self signed program on their PC, so i don't need an overpriced one from Microsoft?

Comment: "Allowed" in what sense? It isn't *illegal*.

Comment: Maybe Microsoft wants to make money of it or so idk, why would they make an certificate?